# QListView with Two QTextEdit 's as Item

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qitemdelegate, qstyleditemdelegate

In Qt Widget Application (c++), a part of my *.ui file consists of a QListView with two QTextEdits as its items like the below figure.

[image]

As you can see custom widget includes two QTextEdit that each one has its text and stylesheet. As I searched on the net, there are solutions like HtmlDelegate classes for rendering text of items on QListView. But these classes only present **ONE** QTextEdit as item for QListView. In future, I want sync the QListView scrol status with a QMultimedia status like Podcast apps. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How many items do you expect to have in your list?

Comment: Maximum 120 items!

Comment: 120 is not so many. Then I think you can just put the widgets to a `QVBoxLayout` and then to `QScrollArea`. You do not need to bother with `QListView` and all the complicated stuff with editable delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well first of all you should create your custom widget like this:

[image]

Then you add it to your **Model** of `QListView` by using `setIndexWidget` function like this:

```
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(120, 1);
    ui->listView->setModel(model);

    for (int r = 0; r < 120; r++)
    {
        ui->listView->setIndexWidget(model->index(r, 0), new CustomTextEdits);
    }
```

**Final Result:**

[image]

you can see the source code here:

https://github.com/parisa-hr/SO-addwidgettoqlistview

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me, but, couldn't we use QML, `ListView`, `ListModel` to handle the data and the rendering?

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            id: items
            Component.onCompleted: {
                for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    let enText = "English Text " + (i + 1);
                    let itText = "Its Translate " + (i + 1);
                    append( { enText, itText } );
                }
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        spacing: 2
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            background: Rectangle {
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 2
            }

            ColumnLayout {
                width: parent.width

                TextInput {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: enText
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    font.pointSize: 12
                    onAccepted: enText = text
                }

                Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 2
                    color: "steelblue"
                }

                TextInput {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: itText
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    font.pointSize: 12
                    font.italic: true
                    color: "red"
                    onAccepted: itText = text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: If we want to have something like this in QML , [Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) is a better choice, isn't it? Your answer raises this question for me.

Comment: Both Repeater and ListView are similar in that they both support a model. ListView has a bonus in that it has built-in "current" item, flickable, and scrollbar. The OP indicated scroll status was important and was already using QListView. But, to be honest the precise use case was somewhat vague.